# Is there a limit on Algolia search filters with boolean operators?

Tags: node.js, algolia

I have an index with a bunch of users that have the following attributes:

- userid
- username
- displayname

I want to search on a subset of users for which I have a list of IDs. EX) `userid:123 OR userid:345 OR ...`

Is there a limit on the number of filters that I can place in a search filter? For example if I have a list of 500 IDs for which I am filtering on, will that cause any issues?

Is there a better way to filter the search to only records matching the array I pass in?

Comment: Have you *tried*?

Comment: @tadman It works for my limited set of data. I don't have a very large data set yet. There's no mention of a limit in their docs either.

Comment: I mean try the stupidest query you think will ever happen in real life, and then multiply that by a factor of 10x. Does it still work? If so, you're fine.